# What are some useful ways to update column data based on two conditions?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two questions on the following code:

```
UPDATE HRBI SET HRBI.PayGroupRegionCode = IIF(HRBI.PayGroupRegionCode = 'UNK' AND HRBI.CompensationGradeProfile = 'Japan JPN', 'APJ',
IIF(HRBI.PayGroupRegionCode = 'UNK' AND HRBI.CompensationGradeProfile = 'Taiwan TWN', 'APJ',
IIF(HRBI.PayGroupRegionCode = 'UNK' AND HRBI.CompensationGradeProfile = 'China CNA', 'APJ',
IIF(HRBI.PayGroupRegionCode = 'UNK' AND HRBI.CompensationGradeProfile = 'Australia AUS', 'APJ',
IIF(HRBI.PayGroupRegionCode = 'UNK' AND HRBI.CompensationGradeProfile = 'Singapore SGP', 'APJ',
IIF(HRBI.PayGroupRegionCode = 'UNK' AND HRBI.CompensationGradeProfile = 'Thailand THA', 'APJ',
IIF(HRBI.PayGroupRegionCode = 'UNK' AND HRBI.CompensationGradeProfile = 'Luxembourg LUX','EMEA',
IIF(HRBI.PayGroupRegionCode = 'UNK' AND HRBI.CompensationGradeProfile = 'Romania ROU', 'EMEA',HRBI.PayGroupRegionCode))))))));
```

1. Does the false condition return the default value (value that was already in the column) that was in PayGroupRegionCode if none of the conditions are met?
2. Is there another/better way to write this?

Comment: It would me much more manageable to have a table populated with the cities, the build your update query against that.

Comment: yes, that makes sense and would work well I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Consider [Switch](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-Function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379) instead of nested `IIf` expressions.  Also use the pattern `CompensationGradeProfile IN (<list of values>)`

```sql
UPDATE HRBI
SET HRBI.PayGroupRegionCode =
    Switch
        (
            HRBI.CompensationGradeProfile IN
                    (
                        'Japan JPN',
                        'Taiwan TWN',
                        'China CNA',
                        'Australia AUS',
                        'Singapore SGP',
                        'Thailand THA'
                    ), 'APJ',
            HRBI.CompensationGradeProfile IN
                    (
                        'Luxembourg LUX',
                        'Romania ROU'
                    ), 'EMEA',
            True, HRBI.PayGroupRegionCode
        )
WHERE HRBI.PayGroupRegionCode = 'UNK';
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that Access SQL dialect supported `Switch`!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're checking for the value in `PayGroupRegionCode` to be something fixed (`"UNK"`), then you can move that to the `WHERE` clause of your query.

Now, let's simplify this:

```
UPDATE HRBI 
SET PayGroupRegionCode = IIF(CompensationGradeProfile = 'Japan JPN', 'APJ',
IIF(CompensationGradeProfile = 'Taiwan TWN', 'APJ',
IIF(CompensationGradeProfile = 'China CNA', 'APJ',
IIF(CompensationGradeProfile = 'Australia AUS', 'APJ',
IIF(CompensationGradeProfile = 'Singapore SGP', 'APJ',
IIF(CompensationGradeProfile = 'Thailand THA', 'APJ',
IIF(CompensationGradeProfile = 'Luxembourg LUX','EMEA',
IIF(CompensationGradeProfile = 'Romania ROU', 'EMEA', HRBI.PayGroupRegionCode))))))))
where PayGroupRegionCode = 'UNK';
```

Now, given that you're updating to two values only, I think the easiest way would be to use two different update queries (easier to read and easy to run):

```
UPDATE HRBI
SET payGroupRegionCode = 'APJ'
WHERE PayGroupRegionCode = 'UNK'
  AND CompensationGradeProfile IN ('Japan JPN', 'Taiwan TWN', 'China CNA', 
                                   'Australia AUS', 'Singapore SGP');
UPDATE HRBI
SET payGroupRegionCode = 'EMEA'
WHERE PayGroupRegionCode = 'UNK'
  AND CompensationGradeProfile IN ('Luxembourg LUX','Romania ROU');
```

Notice that, since you're not using more than one table, you can ommit the table name in the field lists in your query (queries).

*Alternative (not tested)*

It's been a while since I last used Access, but maybe you can try this:

```
UPDATE HRBI
SET payGroupRegionCode = IIF(
        CompensationGradeProfile IN ('Japan JPN', 'Taiwan TWN', 'China CNA', 
                                     'Australia AUS', 'Singapore SGP'),
        'APJ',
        IIF(
            CompensationGradeProfile IN ('Luxembourg LUX','Romania ROU'), 
            'EMEA', 
            PayGroupRegionCode
        )
    )
WHERE PayGroupRegionCode = 'UNK';
```

Comment: I prefer the two query approach as well.  Easier to write and easier to maintain.  If you need it to be atomic, you can wrap both statements in a transaction.

Comment: @BaconBits I prefer that approach too (but I don't know if Access supports transactions)